# Civimail: from address is wrong

Tags: civimail, outbound-email

I need help solving a problem regarding the "from" field when sending mailings via Civimail.  I have the correct person chosen in the "From" field on the compose screen.

[image: Tracey How <thow@besanthill.org]

I also have the name and email address set correctly on the Administer -> Civimail -> From Email Addresses screen.

[image: Image of the From Email Addresses screen]

And here's the edit screen from that.

[image: Image of the from email address option screen]

The problem is that when the mail is actually sent, the "from" address doesn't match when I go to read the message in my inbox.

[image: Image of the sender's name and email in the received message]

As you can see, the name is correct but the email address is different.  Any ideas?  Is there another place I need to set the email correctly?

Thank you,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the email address set in Administer -> System Settings -> Outbound Email was not what it should have been.  I corrected it and now the problem is solved.

Thank you for your help, Pradeep.

Richard

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon what is the email i.e Event registration or Donation receipts or reminders etc

Civi allows you to choose your own from address(name and email) and not from the From address lists for sending one of above-mentioned emails.

So you will need to go into the respective configuration and check under receipt section for From name and From address.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you, Pradeep.  I am sending a mailing directly from Civimail, not events or donation, or any other receipt type--it is an unsolicited mailing.  Where do I find the setting you're describing in this case?  --Richard

Comment: This issue is still plaguing me.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Can you share some screen shot on skype at pradp_nayak or email pradpnayak at gmail dot com?

Comment: I'd be happy to.  What would you like a screenshot of besides those I've included above?

Comment: We can debug together and ask few questions about the sites and what extensions you have installed etc